# Technology behind Google Instant?

Tags: instant

Google Instant is a new search enhancement that shows results as you type. On [the information page for Google Instant](http://www.google.com/instant/), it says "15 new technologies contribute to Google Instant functionality." What are they?

Comment: Those who are in a position to know are unlikely to say...

Comment: Although the 'real Google Instant' might have involved 15 cutting edge technologies and what not, as long as you have a beefy indexed superfast server to return "data-only" search results, building an "instant search" will involve jquery, javascript, html and css and webservices that return results to the client calls

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Google Instant work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the 15 new technologies, but see this [How does Google Instant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work)