# Home Baked Google Instant (Just the fancy AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, instant

Anyone know how you could duplicate the instant nature of Google Instant?
I'm trying to create a similar functionality with hand carved results (basically a huge if statement) on a website.

Some more clarification:

If a user were to type 'phone' in a search bar, contact information would instantly appear below.

more clarification:
I don't really want predictive results, just simply returning results based on keyword instantly below the input bar.

Comment: You may also want to give a look to this question: [How does Google Instant work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work)

Comment: Ah yes thank you, that definitely clears things up. I guess I'm not requiring quite the same functionality...it would be easy to assume I was just another crack pot with a money making scheme that would undoubtedly fail. Alas, I am just trying to get an understanding of how the AJAX functions.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to move the search box on the first keystroke in a box then use ajax to retrieve results? Sounds like the bulk of what you're asking to do...

Business statements -> code

Comment: Nothing to do with business, and no not move the search box...just return the results below. It's not for commercial 'search', just information retrieval.

Comment: then you just want to look at ajax results retrieval... You might start here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this post http://www.rsc-ne-scotland.org.uk/mashe/2010/09/google-custom-instant/ It's a very simple implementation using jquery and Google custom search returning JSON.