# Google Autocomplete - immense speed, no delay

Tags: ajax, performance

Google recently implemented their "Instant" search facility, with results showing as quick as 0.07 seconds. This surely cannot be done with your everyday jQuery AJAX? What methods are Google using to deploy such a quick, slick autocomplete feature which crawls and search billions upon billions of web pages in milliseconds?

Comment: That and http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html

Comment: They also have their own CDN which is local to a lot of ISPs, which helps a lot in situations like these.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work).
It's predictive. The search results are from the first autocomplete suggestion (or the selected one if you hit the down arrow or mouse over a suggestion).