# How does Google's "Search Suggest" (Instant) Work?

Tags: search, design-patterns, database-design, data-structures

This is an example of Google Instant:

[image]

I understood from the following SO question [How does Google Instant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work) that  whenever a user types something an ajax call is made which returns all the relevant '*suggestions*', but, how does it work internally?
What's the architecture for this feature?
Are they using [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure approach or something else?

Comment: It's unlikely that anybody who knows how Google implemented this will tell you. That's probably proprietary information. If you want to know how one might go about implementing this functionality, then ask that question. But don't ask something that the majority of people have no way of knowing, and that those who *do* know can't reveal.

Comment: this is your assumption that google guys who know about this feature won't reveal it. For instance, we all know how google search work which technically from your point of view should've been a secret. https://www.google.com/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/

Comment: To the guy who flagged the question as "primarily opinion based": How is it an opinion based question? I'm not seeking any opinions, I'm expecting a concrete answer to my question.

Comment: I marked it as opinion based for the reason I stated in my comment.

Comment: By the way, the "how search works" page you linked is a completely non-technical overview that describes in general how any search engine works. It's hardly proprietary information. They don't talk about specific algorithms and data structures or implementations at all.